# Permission denied on remote node

Tags: rundeck

I want to copy some configuration files from rundeck servers to remote but I got permission denied since I need root user to perform on destination server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Be sure of 2 things :

- the user you are running rundeck with has permission to acces the .htaccess
  file and its destination path (`/var/rundeck/projects/Shop/config-files/`)

  ```
  [rundeck@rundek-host ~]$ ls -l /var/rundeck/projects/Shop/
  total 0
  drwxrwxr-x 2 rundeck rundeck 21 26 mai   11:40 config-files
  ```
- the user you are connnecting with to the remote session has
  enough permission to access the destination path (`/var/www/html/shop/`) and to copy a file there.

  ```
  [user@remote-host ~]$ ls -l /var/www/html/
  total 0
  drwxrwxr-x 2 rundeck user 11 26 mai   11:50 shop
  ```

You can configure the user and password in 3 ways, refer the official documentation and check your own configuration : 
[Specifying SSH Username](http://rundeck.org/docs/plugins-user-guide/ssh-plugins.html#specifying-ssh-username)